# Incorporating python linter(flake8) in the CI/CD pipeline that use GitHub, Github Actions in a code base that is not in compliance

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github, github-actions, linting

I have a codebase that is not in compliance with flake8. The CI/CD pipeline uses GitHub/GitHub actions. I would like to start adding python flake8 (to check for complexity, errors and code smells) progressively. How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:
https://github.com/py-actions/flake8

Or if you prefer to do it more manually you can use this:

```yaml
name: Python

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:

jobs:
  flake8:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4.1.0
        with:
          python-version: 3

      - name: Install flake8
        run: pip --disable-pip-version-check install flake8

      - name: Lint with flake8
        run: flake8 --count
```